# How to make sshd listen to two ports, but restrict one of them to a single source address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sshd

I need sshd to listen both on port 22225 (allowing connections on that port from any IP) and port 22 (allowing just a single static IP on that port).

In other words, listen on two ports at the same time while whitelisting connections only on one port. Is there a way to do that? I'm running ubuntu server 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure your SSH server to listen to both ports, and then use iptables to restrict access to port 22 to a single IP number. Something like the following (where `x.x.x.x` is the IP number you want to allow):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```